# Changing a TextView's style and text dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, textview, master-detail

I'm trying to make an app like the one in this mockup:

**Supermarket**
[image: Supermarket]

It's a very simple supermarket app. As you can see, there's a TextView at the bottom of the screen that tells me whether my Cart is empty, or has items in it. If the cart is **not** empty, the user is shown the total price he/she must pay. You can also notice that said `TextView`'s style and text change according to a variable (in this case, "totalPrice").

How can I do this in Android? I know I can use simple if statements (`if totalPrice == 0`, then `backgroundColor = grey` and `text = "EmptyCart"`, for example), but this seems somewhat... hardcoded. Is there a better way to do it? As you can see, the `TextView's` style and values also change when on the "Subproducts" activity (some Products have Subproducts, which you can see after clicking on them).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Databinding is the best way rather than boilerplate code.
create a model class and change background of the view using ternary operation in databinding also manage visibility of price text using this.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for. I finished the project last week but forgot to thank you; Data Binding saved my life.

Comment: This is how i tried to do it using a ternary but whenever i change the boolean value, the changes never ot reflected on the UI. just when the ui is initially loaded

Answer (score 1):

To set a textview's text, you use `textView.setText("new text");`  To set its background, its `textView.setBackgroundColor(color)` where the color is the hexcode you want as an integer-  for example 0xFFFF0000 for reg.  Obviously these can be variables as well as hard coded.

Comment: `0x00FF0000` will be completely transparent. It's also probably safer to use `Color.parseColor("#FFFF0000")`.

Comment: Brain fart on my part, I meant FF.  But parseColor should be avoided, it puts a needless and CPU wasting string parse in there.  It should only be used if reading a color from a file

Comment: If you have to write it in code, I'd definitely prefer `0xWHATEVER` to `Color.parseColor("#WHATEVER")`

Answer (score 0):

It can simply be achieved with two `TextView`s in a `RelativeLayout`, and of course, by using basic `TextView`'s methods. As an example layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#1EC4F3">

    <TextView
        android:text="PAY"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$25.79"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just set the colors and text programmatically? It's much easier, and has to be done either way, so that the price is correct.

Comment: Yup, you're right, this is just an example layout and OP will, by all means, need to use basic TextView's methods for updating those TextViews. OP thinks that there is only ONE TextView in the layout in question -- it could be only one, but not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As a last question, would creating a Fragment for the layout in question be better than implementing the layout independently on each activity (i.e., the Products and the Subproducts activities)?

Comment: @Noobuntu Fragments are to go as per design, but you can implement in whatever you prefer.